# Ruby on Rails - select option helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, helper

can someone please help in select helper, as I am new to Ruby On rails.

I have one json object as follow,

```
@response = {"status" => "200", "fruit" => [ {
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => "Apple"
  }, {
    "id" => 2,
    "name" => "Mango"
  } ]
}
```

for which in helper I am returning value "return @response['rateCard']"
Now what I want from this helper to generate such code in view file so it will have selection box like

```
<select name='fruit'>
<option value="1">apple</option>
<option value="2" selected>mango</option>
</select>
```

## please help

Actually I have one helper "Fruits_helper.rb" which is returning

```
def selFruit
    @resp = Fruit.getFruit # this will return @response object as mentioned above

    return @resp['fruit']
end
```

==================================================================================
So in my fruit.html.erb file I am having small piece of code as follows

```
<%= form_for(:AdminLogin) do |f| %>
<div>

<%= select_tag "fruit", options_for_select(selFruit.each{|fruit,key| [fruit[key]=>'name',fruit[key]=>'id']}) %>

<div>
<% end %>
```

============================================================================
the above code gives me o/p as

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
<option value="id1nameApple">id1nameApple</option>
<option value="id2nameMango">id2nameMango</option>
</select>
```

where I want result as apple

Comment: form_for -> form.select, not select_tag. selFruit.each -> selFruit.map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Problem has been solved just by following code, hope it will help other RoR freshers too

```
<%= select_tag "fruit", options_for_select(selFruit.map{|fruit,key| [fruit['name'], fruit['id']]}) %>
```

Comment: with `form_for` the form build `form.select` is the standard way.

Answer (score 4):

If you use (and you should) a `form_for` builder:

```
form.select(:fruit, @response["fruit"].map { |f| [f["name"], f["id"]] })
```

Comment: above code is throwing error for me as "wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)"